# java. lang. NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/GroupLayo ut$Group (the program is not mine)

Tags: javascript, java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Uddm.png)

to some extent, I am a Java coder, the program is not mine, in general, the program is from 2010, but it works on the video. please help me. I can post the program if necessary.

Comment: Why do you created tag to `JavaScript` when you asking about `Java` and also you should to explain your question in a good way and attach your code and error to get your answer - check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I wrote that this is not my file, I tried to decompile it, but decompilers do it with a lot of errors. when I make a tag Java writes to me put one of the popular tags